# Matching excel value of column A and E to a name in column B and D

Tags: excel, vba

Basically I have a huge excel file with numbers that I would like to assign a name to (I start with the name UNKNOWN)

```
   A   |    B
123456 | Unknown  
456875 | Unknown2
```

Assign a sequenced number for different values of rows.
If column A2 = column E25, replace the value of  D25 with UNKNOWN2

Does that make sense?

I am looking for a macro that would do that automatically

Comment: `Does that make sense?` Not to me.... Could you try to post a clearer representation of what your sheet looks like and what data you'd like to add? Phrases like "column E25" and "1,2,3-4000" are very confusing.

Comment: Sorry I have no idea of how to explain myself more clearly lol

Comment: are "Numbers" in one column only?

Comment: no 2, A and E @user3598756

Comment: Please upload an image of the initial situation and one of the desired result

Comment: Please read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's clear enough for me to understand you...

You have numbers in column A and D - for each number you want a specific name.

The names should be listed in column B (for numbers in A) and column E (for numbers in D).

If there are numbers in A which are in D, too, these numbers share the same name.

Try this code:

```
Sub Test()

Dim rng As Range
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, l As Long
Dim firstAddress As String, foundAddress As String

For i = 1 To Rows.Count - 1

    If IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1).Value) Then Exit For

Next i

For j = 1 To Rows.Count - 1

    If IsEmpty(Cells(j, 4).Value) Then Exit For

Next j

Set rng = Range("A1:A" & i & ", D1:D" & j)

l = 1

For k = 1 To i + j

    If k < i Then

        firstAddress = rng.Find(Cells(l, 1).Value, Lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True).Address
        foundAddress = firstAddress

        If Cells(l, 2).Value = "" Then

            Do Until firstAddress = ""

                Cells(Range(foundAddress).Row, Range(foundAddress).Column + 1) = "Name" & k

                foundAddress = rng.Find(Cells(l, 1).Value, Range(foundAddress), Lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True).Address

                If foundAddress = firstAddress Then _
                    Exit Do

            Loop

        End If

    Else

        If k = i Then _
            l = 1

        firstAddress = rng.Find(Cells(l, 4).Value, Lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True).Address
        foundAddress = firstAddress

        If Cells(l, 5).Value = "" Then

            Do Until firstAddress = ""

                Cells(Range(foundAddress).Row, Range(foundAddress).Column + 1) = "Name" & k

                foundAddress = rng.Find(Cells(l, 4).Value, Range(foundAddress), Lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True).Address

                If foundAddress = firstAddress Then _
                    Exit Do

            Loop

        End If

        If l = j - 1 Then _
            Exit Sub

    End If

    l = l + 1

Next k

End Sub
```

Here are pictures - is it what you want?

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhZNR.png)

[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dC3B.png)

Comment: Wow, this actually worked (with some errors which replaced some users) but thanks a bunch, saved me days of work! +1